# What is the correct nesting structure for calculating the Inter-rater reliability or intra class correlation (ICC) with multiple raters?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, agreement-statistics, nested-data, intraclass-correlation

I need to figure out which inter-rater reliability for multiple raters I should calculate. I'm trying to figure out how I should nest or structure certain observations within my dataset in order to run a MultiLevel Regression Model (Mixed Model) in R from which I can calculate the ICC. Several Raters (about 9) have to rate attitudes about 100 participants whom all go through 14 different trials (2 (nice versus cruel) by 7 (seven different scenarios) design) and for each of the 14 trials (for each participant) a Rater has to rate the participant on 6 different topic/issues/attitudes (degree of anger, empathy and so on) on a 5 point Likert-scale. I want to figure out till which degree the Raters agree on the 6 different ratings for each of the fourteen trials for all participants. I figured that the intra class correlation (ICC) is the correct way to go when multiple raters (more than 2) give ratings on the same units (the 14 trials within each of the 100 participants).

I would say that the Ratings reside at the first level of the hierarchical nested structure. But then I get confused. Because I expect Raters to rate similarly in one specific trial for a specific participant on anger or on empathy for example. Within each unique trial and attitude the 9 Raters should give the same rating (and therefore nested within each specific trial?) but ratings are also nested within a specific Rater. Can Anyone help me out here with the my data structure?